# Forking a process, and using pipes to transfer data from file line by line to child process

Tags: c, file, while-loop, pipe, fork

My project is to fork and then use the parent process to read data from a file line by line and then send each line to the child process, which has to use execve to send the line as an argument for bc, and the output has to go back to the parent process. Right now, I'm just trying to send the data to the child and receive it properly, but it doesn't work. I have to use select to figure out if the child has output for the parent to get.

I have a file with 5 lines on it, and I use a while loop to go through the file. For each line I thought I would get the line back from the child, but it only does one line or two and stops. Then I get the same line twice for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wait.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    alarm(60);

    fd_set rfds;
    fd_set r2fds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;
    int retval2;

    int i = argc;
    int rc;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (argv[1],"r");

    char *args[3];
    int j = 0;
    while (j < i)
    {
        args[j] = argv[j+2];
        j++;
    }

    int stdin_pipe_fds[2], stdout_pipe_fds[2], stderr_pipe_fds[2];

    pipe(stdin_pipe_fds);
    pipe(stdout_pipe_fds);
    pipe(stderr_pipe_fds);

    rc = fork();
    if (rc == -1)
    {
        while (rc == -1)
        {
            rc = fork();
        }
    }

    pid_t child;
    pid_t parent;

    if (rc == 0)
    {
        child = getpid();

        close(stdin_pipe_fds[1]);
        close(stdout_pipe_fds[0]);
        close(stdout_pipe_fds[0]);

        close(0);
        dup(stdin_pipe_fds[0]);//, 0);
        close(stdin_pipe_fds[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(stdout_pipe_fds[1]);//,1);
        close(stdout_pipe_fds[1]);
        close(2);
        dup(stderr_pipe_fds[1]);//,2);
        close(stderr_pipe_fds[1]);
    }

    if (rc > 0)
    {
        parent = getpid();

        close(stdin_pipe_fds[0]);
        close(stdout_pipe_fds[1]);
        close(stderr_pipe_fds[1]);
    }

    char str[100];
    char buf2[100];
    char buf[100];

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(stdout_pipe_fds[0], &rfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;



    while ((fgets(str,100,fp)) != NULL)
    {       
        if (rc > 0)
        {   
            int wstatus;
            int wsta;
            int status;
            wsta = write(stdin_pipe_fds[1],str,strlen(str));
            retval = select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

            if (FD_ISSET(stdout_pipe_fds[0], &rfds))
            {
                wstatus = read(stdout_pipe_fds[0], buf2, 100);
                printf("From child: %s\n",buf2);
                if (wstatus == -1)
                {
                    printf("read failed\n");
                    //continue;
                }
                //wsta = write(stdin_pipe_fds[1],str,strlen(str));
            }


        }

        if (rc == 0)
        {
            alarm(60);

            scanf("%s",buf);
            printf("%s", buf);
        }       
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child

you close stdout_pipe_fds[0] twice, and not stderr_pipe_fds[0].

The scanf("%s", buf) will strip the newline from the string; you might not want that.   Stdout, if you started from a terminal, will be line buffered; that is, it will take a newline to trigger an actual write.   Since you snuck in and replaced the underlying FD, it doesn't know that a new buffering strategy may be appropriate.

In the parent:

you treat read and write as if they return a status; they return the number of bytes read or written.   If it reads 0 bytes, the buf will contain the values from the previous read.   I am not sure of the purpose of the read(), I would assume it just messes things up.  I think you need to draw a picture of how the file descriptors are linked.

Suggestions:   There is a generally accepted idiom when using fork:

```
if ((rc = fork()) == 0) {
    /* do child stuff */
} else if (rc != -1) {
    /* do parent stuff */
} else {
    /* do error stuff */
}
```

Which is mainly followed to avoid warping peoples brains.   It is really hard to read when it is interleaved.  The "K" in K&R once quipped that "... if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

The close(0); dup(); is much better expressed as dup2(fd, 0).   The mere fact that you can compile code on your machine assures that dup2 functions correctly.